# Show hourly weather from API using DOM

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to show the hourly weather on my web site from this API: https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp3g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/18.1489/lat/57.3081/data.json

I have a hard time understanding the functions needed to do so. I think I need some sort of loop, but can't figure out what to put in it. This is my code so far:

```
export async function getWeather() {
    var res = await fetch("https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp3g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/18.1489/lat/57.3081/data.json");
    if (res.ok)
      return await res.json();
    else
      alert('HTTP Error: ' + res.status);
  }

--My other file--

import {getWeather} from './fetch.js'

async function generate_weather() {

    var jsonRes = await getWeather();
    var i = 0;

    if(jsonRes.timeSeries[i].validTime == timeNow())
    {
        document.createTextNode(jsonRes.timeSeries[i].parameters[i].values[0] + " grader");
    }
        
}

function timeNow() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    
    return hours;
}

generate_weather();
```

I tried the example below, but it didn't work. Am I missing a step?

```
async function generate_weather() {

    var jsonRes = await getWeather();

    for (let times in jsonRes.timeSeries) {
        let currentTime = times.validTime;
        let date = new Date(currentTime);
        let currentHour = date.getHours();
        
        for (let param in times.parameters) {
            let value = param.values[0];
            let unit = param.unit;
        }
        

    for (var i = 0; i == currentHour;) {
        var newElement = document.createElement('h2');
        var newElementText = document.createTextNode(jsonRes.timeSeries[i].times[i].parameters[0]);

        newElement.appendChild(newElementText);

        document.getElementById("body").appendChild(newElement);
    }
}
}

generate_weather();
```

Answer (score 1):

In response, you have two arrays one for timeseries and other for parameters inside the timeseries-
[image]

So, you will have to use loop inside the loop like this in generate_weather function -

```
for (let times in jsonRes.timeSeries) {
    let currentTime = times.validTime;
    let date = new Date(currentTime);
    let currentHour = date.getHours();
    
    for (let param in times.parameters) {
        let name = param.name;
        let value = param.values[0];
        let unit = param.unit;
        Console.log('Tempreture of ' + name + ' is ' + value + ' ' + unit); // Tempreture of t is 14.8 Cel
    }
}
```

Above code will show the tempreture of every name per every hour, if you need to show the tempreture for any specific name then you can use if/else statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where do I use currentHour?

Comment: As you said you wanted to show the hourly weather then currentHour will help you to find out the temperature of any specific hour.

Comment: I tried your example, but I still can't figure out what's missing. Do I need more steps or did I write something wrong?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you elaborate your requirement more. Do you want to show hourly temp of any specific name and how do you want to show it. Also, Will you call this API every hour or just once?